# Extract data from text/javascript using python

Tags: javascript, python, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

How to extract **'https://www.example.com/get_file/4/b315c8e0d6fad43d89445378b5292eed6981a999ba/174000/174469/174469.mp4/?br=707'** & using 'video_url'

```
[<script src="https://www.example.com/player/kt_player.js?v=5.5.1" type="text/javascript"></script>, <script type="text/javascript">
                            /* <![CDATA[ */
                                                            function getEmbed(width, height) {
                                    if (width && height) {
                                        return '<iframe width="' + width + '" height="' + height + '" src="https://www.example.com/embed/174469" frameborder="0" allowfullscreen webkitallowfullscreen mozallowfullscreen oallowfullscreen msallowfullscreen></iframe>';
                                    }
                                    return '<iframe width="852" height="480" src="https://www.example.com/embed/174469" frameborder="0" allowfullscreen webkitallowfullscreen mozallowfullscreen oallowfullscreen msallowfullscreen></iframe>';
                                }
                            
                            var flashvars = {
                                                                    video_id: '174469',                                                                     video_categories: 'example_category1', 'example_category2',                                                                     video_tags: 'example_tag1', 'example_tag2',                                                                     license_code: '$603825119921245',                                                                   rnd: '1650848189',                                                                  video_url: 'https://www.example.com/get_file/4/b315c8e0d6fad43d89445378b5292eed6981a999ba/174000/174469/174469.mp4/?br=707',                                                                    postfix: '.mp4',                                                                    video_url_text: '480p',                                                                     video_alt_url: 'https://www.example.com/get_file/4/ffafbe6913656c2250c34bf20fd945a5f86898d749/174000/174469/174469_720p.mp4/?br=1290',                                                                  video_alt_url_text: '720p',                                                                     video_alt_url_hd: '1',                                                                  video_alt_url2: 'https://www.example.com/get_file/4/66c8876a9fd8cd3d823d06880c1797b1424f3200df/174000/174469/174469_1080p.mp4/?br=2559',                                                                    video_alt_url2_text: '1080p',                                                                   video_alt_url2_hd: '1',                                                                     preview_url: 'https://www.example.com/contents/videos_screenshots/174000/174469/preview.jpg',                                                                   preview_url1: 'https://www.example.com/contents/videos_screenshots/174000/174469/preview.mp4.jpg',                                                                  preview_height1: '480',                                                                     preview_url2: 'https://www.example.com/contents/videos_screenshots/174000/174469/preview_720p.mp4.jpg',                                                                     preview_height2: '720',                                                                     preview_url3: 'https://www.example.com/contents/videos_screenshots/174000/174469/preview_1080p.mp4.jpg',                                                                    preview_height3: '1080',                                                                    skin: 'youtube.css',                                                                    logo_position: '0,0',                                                                   logo_anchor: 'topleft',                                                                     hide_controlbar: '1',                                                                   hide_style: 'fade',                                                                     volume: '1',                                                                    related_src: 'https://www.example.com/related_videos_html/174469/',                                                                     adv_pre_vast: 'https://twinrdsrv.com/preroll.engine?id=613eb379-62dd-49ef-8299-db2b5b2af4d7&zid=12861&cvs={ClientVideoSupport}&time={TimeOffset}&stdtime={StdTimeOffset}&abr={IsAdblockRequest}&pageurl={PageUrl}&tid={TrackingId}&res={Resolution}&bw={BrowserWidth}&bh={BrowserHeight}&kw={Keywords}&referrerUrl={ReferrerUrl}&pw={PlayerWidth}&ph={PlayerHeight}',                                                                   adv_pre_skip_duration: '5',                                                                     adv_pre_skip_text_time: 'Skip ad in %time',                                                                     adv_pre_skip_text: 'Skip ad',                                                                   adv_post_vast: 'https://twinrdsrv.com/preroll.engine?id=613eb379-62dd-49ef-8299-db2b5b2af4d7&zid=12861&cvs={ClientVideoSupport}&time={TimeOffset}&stdtime={StdTimeOffset}&abr={IsAdblockRequest}&pageurl={PageUrl}&tid={TrackingId}&res={Resolution}&bw={BrowserWidth}&bh={BrowserHeight}&kw={Keywords}&referrerUrl={ReferrerUrl}&pw={PlayerWidth}&ph={PlayerHeight}',                                                                  adv_post_skip_duration: '5',                                                                    adv_post_skip_text_time: 'Skip ad in %time',                                                                    adv_post_skip_text: 'Skip ad',                                                                  lrcv: '1651572296480833989009946',                                                                  vast_timeout1: '10',                                                                    player_width: '882',                                                                    player_height: '496.9014084507',                                                                    embed: '1'                                                          };
                                                        var player_obj = kt_player('kt_player', 'https://www.example.com/player/kt_player.swf?v=5.5.1', '100%', '100%', flashvars);
                                                                window.onload = function() {
                                        $('.pop-adv .btn').click(function(e) {
                                            player_obj.play();
                                        });
                                    };
/* ]]> */
                        </script>]
```

I tried;

```
import json

script= """[<script src="https://www.example.com/player/kt_player.js?v=5.5.1" type="text/javascript"></script>, <script type="text/javascript">
                            /* <![CDATA[ */
                                                            function getEmbed(width, height) {
                                    if (width && height) {
                                        return '<iframe width="' + width + '" height="' + height + '" src="https://www.example.com/embed/174469" frameborder="0" allowfullscreen webkitallowfullscreen mozallowfullscreen oallowfullscreen msallowfullscreen></iframe>';
                                    }
                                    return '<iframe width="852" height="480" src="https://www.example.com/embed/174469" frameborder="0" allowfullscreen webkitallowfullscreen mozallowfullscreen oallowfullscreen msallowfullscreen></iframe>';
                                }
                            
                            var flashvars = {
                                                                    video_id: '174469',                                                                     video_categories: 'example_category1, example_category2',                                                                   video_tags: 'example_tag1, esample_tag2',                                                                   license_code: '$603825119921245',                                                                   rnd: '1650848189',                                                                  video_url: 'https://www.example.com/get_file/4/b315c8e0d6fad43d89445378b5292eed6981a999ba/174000/174469/174469.mp4/?br=707',                                                                    postfix: '.mp4',                                                                    video_url_text: '480p',                                                                     video_alt_url: 'https://www.example.com/get_file/4/ffafbe6913656c2250c34bf20fd945a5f86898d749/174000/174469/174469_720p.mp4/?br=1290',                                                                  video_alt_url_text: '720p',                                                                     video_alt_url_hd: '1',                                                                  video_alt_url2: 'https://www.example.com/get_file/4/66c8876a9fd8cd3d823d06880c1797b1424f3200df/174000/174469/174469_1080p.mp4/?br=2559',                                                                    video_alt_url2_text: '1080p',                                                                   video_alt_url2_hd: '1',                                                                     preview_url: 'https://www.example.com/contents/videos_screenshots/174000/174469/preview.jpg',                                                                   preview_url1: 'https://www.example.com/contents/videos_screenshots/174000/174469/preview.mp4.jpg',                                                                  preview_height1: '480',                                                                     preview_url2: 'https://www.example.com/contents/videos_screenshots/174000/174469/preview_720p.mp4.jpg',                                                                     preview_height2: '720',                                                                     preview_url3: 'https://www.example.com/contents/videos_screenshots/174000/174469/preview_1080p.mp4.jpg',                                                                    preview_height3: '1080',                                                                    skin: 'youtube.css',                                                                    logo_position: '0,0',                                                                   logo_anchor: 'topleft',                                                                     hide_controlbar: '1',                                                                   hide_style: 'fade',                                                                     volume: '1',                                                                    related_src: 'https://www.example.com/related_videos_html/174469/',                                                                     adv_pre_vast: 'https://twinrdsrv.com/preroll.engine?id=613eb379-62dd-49ef-8299-db2b5b2af4d7&zid=12861&cvs={ClientVideoSupport}&time={TimeOffset}&stdtime={StdTimeOffset}&abr={IsAdblockRequest}&pageurl={PageUrl}&tid={TrackingId}&res={Resolution}&bw={BrowserWidth}&bh={BrowserHeight}&kw={Keywords}&referrerUrl={ReferrerUrl}&pw={PlayerWidth}&ph={PlayerHeight}',                                                                   adv_pre_skip_duration: '5',                                                                     adv_pre_skip_text_time: 'Skip ad in %time',                                                                     adv_pre_skip_text: 'Skip ad',                                                                   adv_post_vast: 'https://twinrdsrv.com/preroll.engine?id=613eb379-62dd-49ef-8299-db2b5b2af4d7&zid=12861&cvs={ClientVideoSupport}&time={TimeOffset}&stdtime={StdTimeOffset}&abr={IsAdblockRequest}&pageurl={PageUrl}&tid={TrackingId}&res={Resolution}&bw={BrowserWidth}&bh={BrowserHeight}&kw={Keywords}&referrerUrl={ReferrerUrl}&pw={PlayerWidth}&ph={PlayerHeight}',                                                                  adv_post_skip_duration: '5',                                                                    adv_post_skip_text_time: 'Skip ad in %time',                                                                    adv_post_skip_text: 'Skip ad',                                                                  lrcv: '1651572296480833989009946',                                                                  vast_timeout1: '10',                                                                    player_width: '882',                                                                    player_height: '496.9014084507',                                                                    embed: '1'                                                          };
                                                        var player_obj = kt_player('kt_player', 'https://www.example.com/player/kt_player.swf?v=5.5.1', '100%', '100%', flashvars);
                                                                window.onload = function() {
                                        $('.pop-adv .btn').click(function(e) {
                                            player_obj.play();
                                        });
                                    };
/* ]]> */
                        </script>]"""

json_data= json.loads(script)
print(json_data['video_url'])
```

and got this error,

**json.decoder.JSONDecodeError: Expecting value: line 1 column 2 (char 1)**

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: Help us, help you. Please explain to us what you would require and what you have tried so far, or any errors that you got in as much details as possible.

Comment: @tsamridh86 I need to extract video_url, video_alt_url & video_alt_url2 from this script. I scraped this prase from a url using bs4.

Comment: @lomewi could you post the code of what you tried? and what are the results?

Comment: @tsamridh86 Question updated

Comment: unfortunately, what you are trying to parse is not a json object, hence this method will not work, it's better to search for the substring "video_url", and then copy whatever else is to the right of it

Comment: i'm writing this as a comment as this is not a complete answer but: all you will have to do is: find the string "video_url" there is only 1 in that section, find the nearest `'` symbol and then copy everything from there to the next `'` symbol and then you will get your url. This is going to be a little complicated, it would be better to wait for someone else to come up with a better solution than this

Comment: Yes, you will have to use plain old text manipulation.  If you can isolate the lines starting after `var flashvars` until the `;`, that IS JSON and could be loaded.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's not an ideal solution because it relies on the source document having very consistent formatting, but you could try parsing it "manually" with a regular expression:

The following assumes you've set `script` to contain the text downloaded above.

```py
import re

def extract(name, script):
    return re.search(rf'\b{name}\s*:\s*(\'|")(.*?)\1', script)[2]

extract('video_url', script)
'https://www.example.com/get_file/4/b315c8e0d6fad43d89445378b5292eed6981a999ba/174000/174469/174469.mp4/?br=707'

extract('video_alt_url', script)
'https://www.example.com/get_file/4/ffafbe6913656c2250c34bf20fd945a5f86898d749/174000/174469/174469_720p.mp4/?br=1290'

extract('video_alt_url2', script)
'https://www.example.com/get_file/4/66c8876a9fd8cd3d823d06880c1797b1424f3200df/174000/174469/174469_1080p.mp4/?br=2559'
```

The regex works like so:

- `\b{name}\s*:\s*` matches the `name:`  part with variable spacing allowed
- `('|")(.*?)\1` matches either a `'some_text'` or `"some_text"` style string
- The `[2]` at the end takes the second group, which is the `(.*?)` matching the text inside the quotes